# Is there a sipler way to create a windows installable file for a ms word addin created using officejs

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I was wondering if there is any simpler way to create a executable file of the taskpane addin?

Apart from the solutions provided in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish, So that I could generate a quick file to check installing on my machine

Sorry if my english is not good though

Comment: I feel like you could with a basic webserver packaged into an executable and using side loading (not sure if thats a thing w/ word, I use Excel mostly). But, then you have code all over the place, like my VBA macros, I have tons of users that don't get updates properly. By setting up via proper methods, you get a central code update spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office web add-ins can't be installed using standard techniques such as Windows installer. It is just a web application which should be hosted somewhere on the server and then the manifest file added to the Office365/Exchange tenant or just published to the store. So, methods described in the article are valid. There is no other mechanisms for distributing them individually like you could do in case of COM add-ins.

Comment: I wonder if you could bundle something with a basic webserver and then use side-loading all built into an installer??

Comment: You can host the web application (add-in) anywhere on the web server. Your task is to sideload the add-in.

Answer (score 1):

The methods discussed in that article are the only way to distribute an Office Add-in.